# React this.setState does not rerender component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button which sends a post request, updates serviceStatus in this.state via this.setState method. But it does not trigger a rerender when I press the button. According to the react document, it should trigger a rerender. Code below. How do I make the component rerender?

```
class PowerStatus extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.title = this.props.title
        this.state = {
            initial: {
                loaded: false,
            }
        }
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        ... 
    }

    async onClick() {
        const url = `/api/widgets/start`;
        const body = {
            title: this.title
        }
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.post(url, body);
            this.setState(() => {
                return {
                    ...this.state,
                    serviceStatus: data.start,
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Could not turn on service.")
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.initial.loaded) {
            const colour = this.state.serviceStatus ? "green" : "red";
            return (
                <Grid.Column
                    width={3}
                    style={{textAlign: 'center'}}
                    onClick={this.onClick}
                    className="img-icon"
                    verticalAlign='middle'>
                    <i 
                        className={`fas fa-power-off fa-5x ${colour}`}></i>
                </Grid.Column>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div/>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure you defined initial state,then setState. There's no state in your code

Comment: You only need to return the changed state. Spreading the state is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the state in your constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  ...
  this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  this.state = { 
     loaded: false,
     serviceStatus: null
  };
}
```

Then you can update it and return in your function like:

```
this.setState({ serviceStatus: data.start }, () => { return this.state.serviceStatus });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Actually I did initialise the state but it's my mistake for cutting out in the code. full code here: https://github.com/ashwinath/home-dashboard-spa/blob/master/src/Components/Widget.js#L46